# CSV to NSString results in empty null object

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv

I'm trying to retrieve content of a csv file to NSString. Thats what I do:

```
NSString *strBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"socs" ofType:@"csv"];
NSLog(@"bundle path: %@",strBundle);
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:strBundle
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:nil];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:strBundle]) {
        NSLog(@"file is there!!!");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"no file");
    }
    NSLog(@"file: %@",file);
    NSArray *allLines = [file componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"lines: %lu",(unsigned long)[allLines count]);
```

file manager shows that the file is there. When i try to log the NSString or number of files it says null. I even created NSData object with the content of exactly the same file and when I logged the NSData object, I clearly saw that there is some data. Then when I tried to create NSString with the content of NSData, I had the same result as before - null. Maybe the problem is somewhere in the formatting of the file?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: How big is your CSV file?

Comment: And what do you suppose the error message you chose to ignore reveals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 3 issues:

1. You are passing a `nil` argument to the `error:` parameter in your `stringWithContentsOfFile:` line. If there's a possibility something might go wrong (and apparently there is), you should pass a real argument there so you can figure out what went wrong.
2. You can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]`, but that has a tendency to produce blank "components" between every line. Plain old `@"\n"` works better in virtually all cases I've run into.
3. You should be checking `fileExistsAtPath` before you try to load it into the `NSString`
4. If you were truly able to create an `NSData` object from the path it doesn't necessarily mean it's correct data. But let's say it is, if you were not able to convert it to a `NSString` then you need to check your encoding parameter.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what I was thinking when I passed nil to error. There was error indeed with formatting. What simply opened the file with textwrangler and saved it with utf-8 formatting. It solved the problem, simple as that :) Your post was helpful so I mark it as solved, thanks :)